# Clause analysis of "He was red in the face"

Tags: syntactic-analysis, adverbials

I'm wondering if anyone could tell me how to analyse a clause such as "He was red in the face" – what is "in his face" here? Is it an adverbial, or a complement of "red"?

Thank you!

Comment: It's not _in **his** face_. Copy correctly if you want an answer. It's _red in **the** face_, an idiom. It means his face was red, because he was angry and upset and acting out. It's a warning of possible undesirable behavior to come.

Comment: The PP "in the face" is complement of "red".

Comment: Thanks Bill – exactly what I was wondering about! It seems a bit odd to analyse it as an adverbial... :)